# Passing pointer to pointer to pointer as a function parrameter

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

Could anyone explain me how to pass 2D array of strings to a function using another pointer ? I want to pass array to a function FILL using pointer. In that function i want to copy a string to an array.

```
void FILL(char **array) {

    char buffer[20] = "Hi my name is John."

    array = (char**) malloc ( 1 * sizeof(char*));
    for ( i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {
        array[i] = (char*) malloc ( 20 * sizeof(char*));
        strcpy(array[i],buffer);
    }

}


int main() 
{

 char **array = NULL;

 FILL(array);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to become a [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) and learn about how to emulate *pass by reference in c*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a triple pointer to char (and enjoy being called a [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)):

```
void FILL(char ***array);

int main()
{
    char **array;

    FILL(&array);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, consider returning the allocated memory segment in `FILL` instead of passing a pointer:

```
char **FILL() {
    char **array = ...;

    ...

    return array;
}

int main()
{
    char **array = FILL();
    ...
}
```

Comment: And how to change the inside of the function ? *array?

Comment: Any advantages over using another pointer in your second example?

Comment: @glery Both approaches have their use cases although you could always emulate the second through the first.